# Additivity theorem for algebraic L-theory?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-k-theory

There is an additivity theorem for algebraic K-theory. My question is is there an additivity theorem for algebraic L-theory?

Answer (score 3):

Let me just ignore the appearing decorations. I think the argument should work with all decorations. The $L$-groups of an additive category $\mathcal{A}$ with involution are defined as the cobordism classes or certain chain complexes over $\mathcal{A}$. The group structure is induced by direct sum of chain complexes.

If we have a additive functor between two additive categories $\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}'$, it induces a group homomorphism $L_n(\mathcal{A})\rightarrow L_n(\mathcal{A}')$ by applying it degreewise. Now if we have two such functors $F,F'$  and an element $[C_*]\in L_n(\mathcal{A})$ then 
$$L_n(F\oplus F')([C_*]):=[(F(C_*)\oplus F'(C_*)]=[(F(C_*)]+[F'(C_*)]=(L_n(F)+L_n(F'))(C_*).$$
Thus additivity follows quite immediately from the definition. 
Definitions of the L-groups can be found for example in [Ranicki, The algebraic theory of surgery, I Fuoundations, Prop. 3.2](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/ats1.pdf)

I think $K$-theory is much harder, since the $K$-groups can only be defined as the homotopy groups of some space/spectrum. For $L$-theory those groups can be defined purely algebraically. However the $L$-theory spectra are still needed - for example to define homology with coefficients in L-theory.

Comment: Thanks, Henrik! I agree with you, there should be an additivity theorem for all decorations. Probably some algebraic argument following the above argument you gave.

Comment: The additivity theorem in K-theory says that for an exact category $\mathscr{C}$ the functor $s\times t \colon SES(\mathscr{C}) \to \mathscr{C} \times \mathscr{C}$ induces a homotopy equivalence on K-theory spaces. Here $SES(\mathscr{C})$ is the category of short exact sequences in $\mathscr{C}$ and $s$ and $t$ project on the first and last elements of a sequence, respectively. Is there something like this in L-theory?

Comment: Jacob Lurie defined L-theory for stable $\infty$ categories with some additional structure. Maybe you can find something in his lecture notes.